# Tomcat auto unpack WAR file changed the last modified time of files

Tags: java, tomcat, war

I experienced an issue when I tried to deploy a WAR file to tomcat.
While the auto unpack process from tomcat, the last modified date of unpack files were being modified. 
The date of unpack web app. files became 12 hours faster, and this results several miscellaneous errors.

I tried to unpack manually via jar -xvf, the last modified date of files remain unchanged.
I also tested in a local tomcat (same timezone with dev. env.), nothing changed in last modified date.

It seems the tomcat timezone issue, does setup on tomcat I can do to solve out this issue?
Great thanks for any help.

Environment:
Tomcat 6 on linux, with GMT-4 timezone both set in server and tomcat
the WAR file created by machine with GMT+8 timezone set

Comment: I get this problem also. Have u found out why?

Comment: nope, I require to unpack and repack the WAR on the deployment machine  to make the WAR file work.

Comment: Have you tried setting timezone in Tomcat?

in tomcat/bin/setenv.bat

`-Duser.timezone=America/New_York`

in tomcat/webapps/ROOT/classes/system-ext.properties

`user.timezone=America/New_York`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, the application was setting the default timezone from within Tomcat as the application was being initialized.  The difference introduced by the change in timezones matched the offset in the file modification times.

I was surprised that any code within the app could run before being unpacked, but the Tomcat container does give the application an opportunity to run initialization code prior to all files being unpacked.

Look for an occurrence of `TimeZone.setDefault()` and try removing the call or moving the call later in the initialization sequence.

**Helpful clues:**

This JSP told me that the application was always running with a specific timezone regardless of the environment settings:

```
<html> 
<body> 
<h2>Current Timezone</h2> 
<%    java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();       
      java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("zzz"); %> 
<%=sdf.format(date)%> 
</body> 
</html>
```

In the log files, I could see the instant the timezone was changing (four hour jump).  It happens at the time the app is loaded.

*Note: Once set, the timezone will stay set until Tomcat is restarted.*

```
Sep 18, 2015 2:34:26 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8443
Sep 18, 2015 2:34:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 285 ms
Sep 18, 2015 2:34:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Sep 18, 2015 2:34:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.24
Sep 18, 2015 2:34:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive myWebapp.war
Sep 18, 2015 6:34:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Sep 18, 2015 6:34:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter INFO: loaded (conf ok)
Sep 18, 2015 6:34:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: struts: []: Verifying ModuleConfig for this module
Sep 18, 2015 6:34:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: struts: []: Verification of ModuleConfig has been completed
Sep 18, 2015 6:34:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: struts: []: Verifying ModuleConfig for this module
```